# Ubuntu 12.04. Compiz Failure. Computer has nothing to use

Tags: 11.10, compiz

I updated to Ubuntu 12.04 with Compiz..now Compiz is failing and I have no tool bars or ways of getting to applications except for firefox from a link presented from sending an error report. How am I supposed to:

1. Fix this mess with no navigation to get to the terminal, or software center.
2. When will this problem be fixed?
3. When I updated the system why didn't it change me back to the crappy Unity interface  (No offense).
4. If it can't be fixed how do I get my files back?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can goto terminal if no gui is working using shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. To solve the problem,
   Reset unity and compiz settings. Every settings of compiz will be resetted.

   - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>
   - Login using your username and password
   - Reset compiz by executing `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`
   - Reset unity , by executing `unity --reset`
   - Optionally you can reset launcher icons by executing `unity --reset-icons`
   - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to login screen. However I recommend a restart by executing `sudo reboot`. *Let us know if it worked.*
3. When you updated the system, possibly your changes in previous version made some conflicting changes with the update.
4. You can go to terminal as stated in step 1, and then run `nautilus` to open the file browser to get your files back.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the different "fixes". The only one that worked for me was as follows.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

After that and a reboot all GUI was there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please note that it's advisable to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing or updating software from the command-line. `sudo apt-get update` fetches updated information about what packages are available in what versions from where.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the shortcuts were not working. I couldn't even start terminal.

I found the solution here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/194996

On fresh install, Ubuntu 12.04 ran Compiz alright. I ran the Update Manager, rebooted and Compiz was good. After installing Additional Drivers, i.e. Nvidia, Compiz crashed and nothing but wallpaper appears. Right-click on screen works and I clicked on Change Desktop Background, then All Settings. I went to Additional Drivers and uninstalled Nvidia. Rebooted and all is well again. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I had this exact problem and tried everything here. Dumitru's solution worked except that I did not have to uninstall the driver. Switching from "version current" to "version current-updates" and then rebooting worked.