# How can I remove Compiz?

Tags: unity

I'd like some help to fix another unity issue.
After last update, my system broke.
For example, when I execute a 'ls' command, the screen breaks and does not show anything. Sometimes, just the beggining is shown.

How can I fix it?

I don't want use another X, for now...

Thanks

Comment: Try to log in with Unity 2D (that does not use Compiz)

Comment: It does not work for me..
This problem does not happens in "Gnome no effects" mode only

Comment: This did for me months ago

http://askubuntu.com/questions/154112/how-do-i-disable-compiz-and-enable-metacity-with-the-command-line

Comment: Hello, I get this issue fixed!

Comment: Hello, I get this issue fixed!
When I was trying to re-install my drivers with commands:

_sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sarvatt/intel-sna && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y_

_sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y_

A message was showed to me, so I did follow the tip and create a xorg.conf with with content:

Section "Device"
         Identifier "intel"
         Driver     "intel"
         Option     "AccelMethotd" "uxa"
EndSection

Just it!

I hope it helps!

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before removing Compiz you might wanto to try and reset it

1.Press Alt + ctrl + F1

2.Login using your username and password

3.Reset compiz by executing `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`

4.Reset unity , by executing `unity --reset`

5.Optionally you can reset launcher icons by executing unity `--reset-icons`

6.Press Alt + ctrl + F7 to get back to login screen. However I recommend a restart by executing `sudo reboot`. Let us know if it worked.

[Cerdits to Web-E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127782/ubuntu-12-04-compiz-failure-computer-has-nothing-to-use)

## To remove compiz and compiz packages type this in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge compiz compiz-plugins-main-default libcompizconfig0`

**Warning:** Removing compiz also removes the packages unity & ubuntu-desktop.

**Warning:** Removing libcompizconfig0 also removes ubuntu-tweak.

Thus you will lose the ability to log into the unity or unity-2d desktops.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87287/can-i-uninstall-compiz-if-only-using-gnome-shell)

More info here: [How can I remove and re-install Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity)

And here: [Ubuntu 12.04. Compiz Failure. Computer has nothing to use](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127782/ubuntu-12-04-compiz-failure-computer-has-nothing-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ubuntu Gnome. It doesn't use Compiz and still has as much, of not more eye candy as Ubuntu.

I have a multi boot system, and Ubuntu Gnome is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to delete compiz, which will have many dependencies issues with Unity and Gnome etc, how about just going ahead to install other Window Manager?   The last time I tried to uninstall / delete Unity/compiz, I ended having to reinstall the entire OS.

For example:   Xubuntu:

apt-get install xubuntu-desktop.

Or you can try i3, awesome, lxde etc.

And then at the login screen, select the appropriate windows manager - making sure you avoid Gnome, Unity or compiz.

After logging in, "ps -ef" and you can easily verify that compiz is not running.