# Questions about compiz, sound control and mkv movies

Tags: sound, video, compiz, mkv

I'm totally fresh with Ubuntu. I've got the newest (16.04) release, my laptop is Lenovo Y50-70.

My issues:

1. How do I get rid of compiz?
2. Sounds, like music or sounds from movies are... like really deep, the quality is awful.
3. MKV movies are really, really silent.

I need a laptop just for internet, movies and music, but Ubuntu doesn't works for me in 2/3.

Any help?

Comment: Please split this into individual questions!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sound :
1- goto setting -> sound -> allow louder than 100%
2- pulse audio may be recommended it's an equalizer like Dolby for installation

> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

for mkv files install vlc

> sudo apt-get install vlc

it works for me correctly

3-for compiz i don't recommend to remove it you should write what's your problem with it , if all you want to remove it look at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182160/how-can-i-remove-compiz).

Comment: Ok, sounds good, mkv movies are good, thanks a lot! For compiz - i would like to change the unity graphical environment for the gnome - it just suits me better.  Any ideas?

Comment: take a look to this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/614657/install-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-15-04

Comment: but i recommend install ubuntu gnome instead of installing desktop because desktop take much amount of memory , processor and install new application to do that goto https://ubuntugnome.org/