# Can I change my window manager without changing my DE?

Tags: compiz

I am currently running Ubuntu Studio with Budgie as its DE, I then installed Compiz (Since I want the jiggley/wobbly windows) and when I used `compiz --replace` it's looking weird and some functions are unusable (like dragging desktop) and some of the minimize, maximize, and close buttons are on the bottom of the top panel of budgie.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: I do remember trying it but it would boot in Mutter

Comment: I'd expect a simple logout & login to be enough... It's all I need to do when I test issues by swapping out *default* DM with another  (note: I'm no expert with Budgie though, most of my testing is with other *flavors* & *desktops*)

Comment: I'll try that thank you!

Comment: Update: it seems like I can't logout, the logout confirmation pop up isn't showing

Comment: I tried your same thing, and it locked up the desktop on me.  I had to do Ctrl+Alt+F3 to a TTY session and reboot from there.  It took me back to Compton that I run and my system is in a usable state again.  The command of `compiz --replace` only replaces the WM just for that session is all.

Comment: So should I set it as my default WM? But when I tested compiz, there's some problem, will that still be present?

Comment: I have been looking around out there and I can't seem to find a 100% answer to it, but some I have seen claim that Budgie doesn't like compiz.  Here is one example:  https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/how-to-enable-compiz/1996

Comment: Not an answer but some background reading: https://askubuntu.com/questions/182160/how-can-i-remove-compiz

Comment: Thank you everyone, will read it later!

Comment: Compiz will work flawlessly only with MATE.

Answer (score 0):

Some DEs, like GNOME, don't support

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME#Use_a_different_window_manager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).